# In Python Tkinter, I have successfully made a keybind but it only works when I am clicked into the tkinter window.

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, key-bindings

> In Python Tkinter, I have successfully made a keybind but it only
>   works when I am clicked into the tkinter window.

**I want to be able to use the keybinds even when I am interacting with other programs even when they are full screen.** (I am making an auto clicker and it is not possible to open the tkinter window and then click the key when you are mid game.)

Comment: Imagine the chaos that would result if programs did this.  You're typing something and suddenly the keystroke doesn't go to the program you're looking at. Some other program, even one that was invisible, suddenly wakes up and responds.  As far as I know, no GUI environment has ever supported this kind of thing.

Comment: You will need to hook into the OS hotkeys to do this. You can't do it with `bind`.

Comment: @Novel Thank you. It worked. I am very happy with how fast people replied.

Comment: @PaulCornelius I know but the keys are very specific. Thank you for your fast reply.

Comment: @NicholasFicara can you share how it worked? I'm having the same issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do what you want with tkinter. Tkinter bindings only work within windows created by tkinter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The coments above suggested some libraries.